# How a new view in Tab bar app, that is not part of tab bar, but does not hid the tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tabbar

I have a tab bar app, created from the template. One of the views is a tableview, and when the user touches the header I have a new tableview flip over to show some new data.
When the new tableview displays, it hides the tab bar. I want the table bar to be visable and active. 
I cant seem to work out how to do this. 
Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Apologies if this is a dumb question. Im sure its going to be easy. or impossible.

Comment: How are you displaying the new tableview? Push, modelview or something else?

Comment: ModalView. Im using the flip animation.

Comment: Ive been able to achieve it by adding a nav bar, but then it doesnt flip. and I would prefer to not have the navigation bar.

Comment: apologies for the shocking title of this question. think i was half asleep when I wrote that.

Comment: Title needs more tab bar. :) I think you can edit your own question title

Answer (score 0):

It hides the tab bar because you're presenting it modally.  Use `+[UIView setAnimationTransition:forView:]`, or `+[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:]` instead:

```
- (void)showBackSide
{
    UIView *superview = [frontSideView superview];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:superview cache:YES];
    [frontSideView removeFromSuperview];
    [superview addSubview:backSideView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```